# How to change one value in a list of values in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am using python 3.9.6 and have a cti file which has data for multiple chemical reactions. I have attached an image of the file. I want to be able to go to the line under # Reaction 1, so line 2028 and change 3.547000e+15 to 2 times this value(7.094000e+15):

```
#Reaction 1
reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [3.547000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0])

#Reaction 1
reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [7.094000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0])
```

I wrote a code that works, but I have to manually replace 3.547000E+15 with 7.094000e+15 using this code. The reason I do not want to do this, is that later on I want to be able to change the first value between the [] brackets, just like 3.547000E+15 for Reaction 1, for multiple Reactions at once and I do not want to have to manually write the number I want to replace and what to replace it with. Is there a way for me to do this?

I was thinking that there might be a way to define 3.547000E+15 without having to type it out. I know its between brackets [] and its the first variable there, so is there a way to define it as "first value in brackets"? I have attached a dummy code with what I want my code to do.

Any help or tips are greatly appreciated, thank you.
I have attached an image of my code and dummy code.

Comment: Hey, try to reframe the question without using any chemistry concepts, just what is the Python question at hand, also if there is a list you are dealing with, write the list so that someone can run that code, for example l = [1, 2, 3]

Comment: Is this "cti" a text file or a binary file? However, to change a single value in a file, you would have to store all the values temporarily in a list, and make all the changes that you want, and then at the end of the program, write it all to the file. But due to floating point numbers and multiple reactions it would take a hell lot of a time.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I actually have a question. Can you see the images I have attached to my post? There should be images showing my code and an example of the cti file, but I don't know if you can see it.

Comment: @Frank Piccolo: I can definitely reframe my question, I can make a new post and include my code in the text instead of as an image, if that's easier.

Comment: @Programmin-in-Python: I'm sorry, I am really new at this so I am not sure, the file contains text as well as numbers. But the line I am trying to change is:        reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', [3.547000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0]). Not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correct but `list[0]` would reffer to first in the list list... and then you can `list[0] *= 2`... something like this:

```
manipout = [3.547000e+15, -0.406, 16599.0]

#Reaction 1
reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', manipout)

manipout[0] *= 2

#Reaction 1
reaction('h + o2 <=> o + oh', manipout)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I actually reworded and reposted this question as Frank Piccolo suggested and received many responses that worked and solved my problem. But thank you again for your response.